# Usuario y la contraseña incorrecta

Tags: contraseña

Es común en muchos sistemas al insertar el usuario y la contraseña incorrecta, el sistema indica que uno de ellos está mal, pero no exactamente cuál (esto sucede en el SO).

La pregunta es: ¿Esto sucede para proteger los datos? ¿O podría decir que es porque es más fácil hacer de esta manera?

Por ejemplo, quien tiene cuenta en Google sabe que hoy en día ellos piden primero el correo electrónico, para después de la validación, pidan la contraseña.

Answer (score 0):

Notificarle al usuario que tiene error en su nombre o contraseña se hace por razones de seguridad, para evitar mineria de informacion sobre la victima.

Asi es potencial atacante no va a poder descartar los casos exitosos. (pude sacar el usuario, ahora me falta contraseña).

> Google sabe que hoy en día ellos piden primero el correo electrónico, para después de la validación, pidan la contraseña.

Esta tecnica antes se usaba en los lugares publicos con altos riesgos de algun ataque.(casinos, reuniones con tematicas religiosas, etc) Donde la entrada al lugar principal la separaban 2 puestos de seguridad. (uno atras de otro)

El primer puesto (zona 1) tenia el nivel de seguridad medio, donde la gente pasaba relativamente rapido y no se desesperaba por hacer estos largos tramites de revision. En ese cuarto ya podrian sacar las camperas en los dias frios, tomar algun trago, etc..

El segundo puesto (zona 2) tenia el nivel de seguridad alto, con detector de metales, etc..

Pasando este la persona entrada al lugar principal.

Lo mismo se implemento en el login, donde el 1er nivel es un dato "no tan critico" - mail, y el segundo nivel "critico" - password

Separarlo en 2 niveles, aceleran el proceso de login, su verificacion/validacion se hace mas eficiente, mas segura para el usuario, menos pesada para procesar y validar.